# Aho-Corasick Algo in c/c++ for hex

Tags: c++, c, antivirus

my problem - i am trying to use aho-corasick algo that i found for c++ while searching net, it currently only search for char based string, i want it to modify it to search for hex based string of varied character. any help to improve the code is greatly appreciated. if i just modify my string text it goes into an ifinite loop.

```
int buildMatchingMachine(const vector<string> &words, char lowestChar = 'a', char highestChar = 'z')

{

    memset(out, 0, sizeof out);

    memset(f, -1, sizeof f);

    memset(g, -1, sizeof g);

    int states = 1; // Initially, we just have the 0 state

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)

    {

        const string &keyword = words[i];

        int currentState = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < keyword.size(); ++j)

        {

            int c = keyword[j] - lowestChar;

            if (g[currentState][c] == -1)

            { // Allocate a new node

                g[currentState][c] = states++;

            }

            currentState = g[currentState][c];

        }

        out[currentState] |= (1 << i); // There's a match of keywords[i] at node currentState.

    }

    // State 0 should have an outgoing edge for all characters.

    for (int c = 0; c < MAXC; ++c)

    {

        if (g[0][c] == -1)

        {

            g[0][c] = 0;

        }

    }



// Now, let's build the failure function

queue<int> q;

for (int c = 0; c <= highestChar - lowestChar; ++c)

{ // Iterate over every possible input

    // All nodes s of depth 1 have f[s] = 0

    if (g[0][c] != -1 && g[0][c] != 0)

    {

        f[g[0][c]] = 0;

        q.push(g[0][c]);

    }

}

while (q.size())

{

    int state = q.front();

    q.pop();

    for (int c = 0; c <= highestChar - lowestChar; ++c)

    {

        if (g[state][c] != -1)

        {

            int failure = f[state];

            while (g[failure][c] == -1)

            {

                failure = f[failure];

            }

            failure = g[failure][c];

            f[g[state][c]] = failure;

            out[g[state][c]] |= out[failure]; // Merge out values

            q.push(g[state][c]);

        }

    }

}



return states;

}

int openFile::findNextState(int currentState, char nextInput, char lowestChar = 'a')
{

    int answer = currentState;

    int c = nextInput - lowestChar;

    while (g[answer][c] == -1)

        answer = f[answer];

    return g[answer][c];

}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/andmej/1233426

Comment: And what have you tried? **This is not a free code writing service**

Comment: @RiggsFolly: well he copied that piece of code. Doesn't that count as a honest effort?  (Oh for the "Lacks minimal understanding" Close Reason!)

Comment: @Jongware +1 for a new `Close Reason` of `Lacks minimal understanding` or maybe `Stole this piece of code but I dont understand it`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: [it used to be there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back) ...

Comment: i will put my updated code once i get it working to some level

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution, you just need to redefine the lowest char and highest char of hex based symbols to its corresponding ascii value not int value also change the MAXS and MAXC to suitable number, now the code works for hex based values.